# Excel complex formula example

Tags: excel

So I would greatly appreciate your help I'm having quite a struggle.  What I need currently is listed below. To begin I have a data set with many individuals and information. There are a few columns that I'm interested in.

---

**Table 1:**

So each `Individual` is either labeled as `Free`, `Arc 1`, `Arc 2` or `Arc 3`. Each individual also has a number of people associated with it and lastly a cost.

```
Individual  | # of people  | Cost  | Type | Compliant with Costs?
A           |3             |45     |Free  |Yes/No?
B           |2             |57     |Arc 2 |
```

**Table 2:**

I then have a table below that is broken out. Free can have 1 2 or 3 individuals and cost can be between 20 - 30 dollars for 1 30-40 for 2 and 40-50 for 3.

```
            |Free  |Arc 1 |Arc2  | Arc 3    
# of people | Cost | Cost | Cost | Cost
1           |20-30 |30-40 | 60-70| 90-100
2           |30-40 |40-50 | 70-80| 100-110
3           |40-50 |60-70 | 80-90| 110-120
```

---

So i want to take the `Individual` column noted above and say if Individual A1 is in Free and has 3 individuals is their cost between 40-50 dollars, if so yes, if not no.

I know this will use some if formulas probably many, I tried `Index(match())` and such too but couldn't figure it out if you could help that would be greatly appreciated.

Below is an example of a sample Excel file, it looks easy with just two individuals but there are hundreds so I'm hoping there is an easy formula.  Again any help is greatly appreciated.

---

*[Excel Screenshot Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmSgz.png) (Same as example above)*

Answer (score 2):

If you change your reference table as follows, you can use a sumifs easily to pull the min and the max and see if your cost is in between

```
#   Type    Min Max
1   Free    20  30
1   Arc 1   60  70
2   Free    30  40
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the best way would be to restructure your reference table, but if you'd like to know how to get your answer as is, you can use a combination of `=INDEX(MATCH(),MATCH())`,`=LEFT()` and `=MID()` to get your answer, as in the following example:

---

The formula in `E2` is:

```
=IF(AND(C2>= (LEFT(INDEX($I$1:$M$5,MATCH(B2,$I$1:$I$5,0),MATCH(D2,$I$1:$M$1,0)),FIND("-",INDEX($I$1:$M$5,MATCH(B2,$I$1:$I$5,0),MATCH(D2,$I$1:$M$1,0)))-1)*1), C2<=MID(INDEX($I$1:$M$5,MATCH(B2,$I$1:$I$5,0),MATCH(D2,$I$1:$M$1,0)),FIND("-",INDEX($I$1:$M$5,MATCH(B2,$I$1:$I$5,0),MATCH(D2,$I$1:$M$1,0)))+1,256)*1),"Yes","No")
```

[image]
[image]